# How to view the configuration of a compute in the past in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Given a timestamp in the past and an instance-id, is there any way to view the instance configuration of a specific instance at the given timestamp programatically using python client libraries? (the whole configuration that normally **compute_v1** API gives when we use `instancesClient.list()` method)

What I want to get is the changes made to the VM since the last year, including the configuration of the VM for each change programatically using python client libraries

We can use `logging.Client.list_entries()` to view the changes made to the VMs but I found that we cant see the configuration of a VM instance at the point of time, just what changes were done to it.

Comment: You can look for audit logs entry on type "create compute engine" and you will see all the parameters provided to the APIs.

Comment: lets say that the instance is created on 2018, i want to view the configuration of the compute instance in Jan 1, 2020(including the machine type, cpus, disks etc...) backtracking from 2018 to 2020 is very hard, due to the fact that there will be many logs generated for that instance and it is programatically harder to calculate the configuration of VM at a timestamp from that start with the audit logs

Comment: If you did not save the logs, google did not do that for you either. i.e. you can't have this information.

Comment: I saved the logs, but how to know the machine configuration of a VM instance at a particular point of time using that logs programatically

Comment: Oh and there is no option to "not save" that logs by the way, those will be stored in Admin activity audit logs and System Event audit logs which cant be disabled

Comment: Google Cloud does not have a time machine for Compute Engine configurations. You can reconstruct changes by manually parsing the logs. Logs are not retained forever, there is a retention period [link[(https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods).